# JSOUP: How to get ID-s with different ending

Tags: java, android, html, css, jsoup

I need to get HTML items with similar ID-s. The format of the ID is "yritusXXXX", where XXXX is four numbers that I do not know. Numbers do not increase or decrease, there is no system for them. 
So, how can I get all items with ID format "yritusXXXX" where X is random number?

Example code:

```
<div id="yritus7212" style="width:600px; font-size:13px; display: none;">

                    <div id="aeg">DATE<br />
                                  LOCATION</div>

                    <div id="pealk">HEADING</div>

                <div id="sisu"><p>And more text...</p>
<p>Some text...</p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a css wildcard selector like this

```
div[id^="yritus"]
```

Comment: Leaving the " out, it did work. 
So, the correct answer is:  div[id^=yritus]
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a single css style for all those ID's, you could use something like:

```
div[id^='yritus']{color: red};
```

If you need something else, than you should rephrase your question and be more specific on what your expected output should be.

Comment: Well, I wrote about JSOUP... So, I wanted to find all div-s with id="yritusXXXX"
Thanks for Your answer.